# How Hazecast BatchStage work with memory?

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I am new to Hazelcast jet and I am trying to join to datas but I want to know how it will occupy memory and how much and what it best practice to do it?

Here is my code:

```java
BatchStage<Map<String,Object>> batch1= pipeline.readFrom(companyListBatchSource);
BatchStage<Map<String,Object>> batch2= pipeline.readFrom(employeeListBatchSource);

//Getting group by key
BatchStageWithKey<Map<String,Object>, Object> jdbcGroupByKey = 
    batch1.groupingKey(a -> a.getSource1().get(col1));
BatchStageWithKey<Map<String,Object>, Object> fileGroupByKey = 
    batch2.groupingKey(b -> b.getSource1().get(col2));

//trying to join but not sure what exactly is happening.
BatchStage<Entry<String, Tuple2<List<Object>, List<Object>>>> d = 
    jdbcGroupByKey.aggregate2(toList(), fileGroupByKey, toList());
```

I want to know will batch1 and batch2 will fetch all the data first and store it and then do joining or will it do streaming of records record by record?

Can anyone explain it how exactly it work as I have to work with big data also and in that case if it's store data it can cause server.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it's a so-called global aggregation. Since we don't know the order of the input, we have to accumulate whole input. And since your aggregation is `toList()`, we have to store all the items. Therefore, to run this job you'll need to load all items into memory.

There's also more to that - we optimize the pipeline for throughput, not for memory usage, so we'll do so called two-stage aggregation. In the first stage we'll group by the key locally, and then send the pre-aggregated results over network to calculate the final aggregation. Since you're aggregating to a list, the job will in the end need double the amount of all items in both sources.

Currently there's no easy way to do it more efficiently if, for example, one or both sides are indexed by the grouping key.

Comment: Okay I understand your point, but do you have any idea so who can we make it useful with big data? As in big data either I have to increase memory or it will go too slow right?

Comment: @user3458271, if you work with big data, you should not expect to load all data in memory. What you're asking for is to join two unsorted sets. If you index at least one side, you can reduce memory from O(n) to O(1).

Comment: Hmm, yes you are right, I understand we cannot load all data that will crash my server, can we do it in paginated form something like fetch paginated data from both sources and do join, aggregation, grouping, sorting etc. and return cumulated data?